# Pandas Filtering based on the length of the same kind variables in a column

Tags: python, pandas

In my real case I have a set of time series related to different IDs stored in a single `DataFrame`
Some are composed by 400 samples, some by 1000 samples, some by 2000.
They are stored in the same df and:

***I would like to drop all the IDs made up of time series shorter than a custom length.***

I wrote the following code, but I think is very ugly and inefficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict={"samples":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],"id":["a","b","c","b","b","b","c","c","c"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dict)

df_id=pd.DataFrame()

for i in set(df.id):
  df_filtered=df[df.id==i]
  len_id=len(df_filtered.samples)

  if len_id>3: #3 is just a random choice for this example
    df_id=df_id.append(df_filtered)
print(df_id)
```

Output:

```
   samples id
2        3  c
6        7  c
7        8  c
8        9  c
1        2  b
3        4  b
4        5  b
5        6  b
```

How to improve it in a more Pythonic way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good answer by Juho. Another option is a [**`groupby-filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```py
df.groupby('id').filter(lambda group: len(group) > 3)

#    samples id
# 1        2  b
# 2        3  c
# 3        4  b
# 4        5  b
# 5        6  b
# 6        7  c
# 7        8  c
# 8        9  c
```

To match your output order exactly, add a descending `id` sort: `.sort_values('id', ascending=False)`

Comment: This is neat as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions. For example, you can use a groupby-transform and drop the "small" samples. An appropriate solution will depend on what your requirements are more closely, i.e., will you do the preprocessing once, and then drop different samples?

Anyway, consider:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"samples": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], "id": ["a","b","c","b","b","b","c","c","c"]})

df["counts"] = df.groupby("id")["samples"].transform("count")
df[df["counts"] > 3]

# Or if you want:
df[df["counts"] > 3].drop(columns="counts")
```

By the way, avoid using `dict` as a variable name.